# Rails 4 and ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncable

I am building a real time chat into a rails 4 application. It seems `ActionCable` is the tool for this kind of job.

Is it possible to use `ActionCable` in rails 4 or do I have update to rails 5?

I cannot find any introduction for `ActionCable` with rails 4.

Comment: fayewebsocket gem you can use https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ActionCable is just a rails-5 way to handle websockets.
For current rails there is Faye(https://github.com/faye) with multiple wrappers like private-pub and faye-rails.

Also you do not have to write the websocket handler in ruby at all

Comment: It took me 2 days to figuring it out how faye works thanks

Answer (score 8):

Rails, in and of itself, is just a collection of various Rubygems.  ActionCable is just a new gem added to the collection with Rails 5.  You can install ActionCable by itself via your Gemfile:

`gem 'actioncable', '~> 5.0.0.beta3'`

Then just go about setting it up.  Here is a decent write up on it:

http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/rails-5-preview-action-cable/

Comment: Worth noting that trying to install actioncable 5.0.0.1 on Rails 4 is not possible, as it depends on actionpack 5.0.0.1, which seems to depend on Rails 5.